# retrieving files from ftp to specific os directory using python 3

Tags: python-3.x, ftp

I'm trying to automate a daily ftp transfer using a Python3 script. I'm having a small issue though with writing the files were i want them to be. This is what I'm doing:

```
import time, os
from ftplib import FTP
from datetime import datetime

today=time.strftime('%d%m%y')
dirName='mydir'+today

if not os.path.exists(dirName):
    os.mkdir(dirName)
    print("Directory " , dirName ,  " Created ")
else:    
    print("Directory " , dirName ,  " already exists")

os.chdir(dirName)

start = datetime.now()
ftp = FTP('ftp')
ftp.login('user','pass')
ftpdir='localdir'+today
ftp.cwd(ftpdir)

# Get All Files
files = ftp.nlst()

# Print out the files
for file in files:
    print("Downloading..." + file)
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + file, open(dirName + file, 'wb').write)

ftp.close()
```

what I get with this code is that all the downloaded ftp files stay in the folder level above "today" while their filename start with the "today" str.

Can someone give a hand here please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved the issue with a bar:

```
# Print out the files
for file in files:
    print("Downloading..." + file)
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + file, open(dirName + '\\' + file, 'wb').write)

ftp.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the path components. For platform independent solution, use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
import os

dirName = os.path.join('mydir', today)
```